# Al hacer clic en los botones de paginación, una paginación tiende a cambiar los valores de la otra

Tags: javascript, json, fetch

He creado una paginación en Javascript funcional, que permite a través del atributo "data- *" (HTML) solicitar distintos parámetros que permiten crearla, pero solo funciona bien si utilizo solo "1 paginación"; y si decido agregar otro, con otra información, en teoría funciona.
Al hacer clic en los botones, aparecen problemas como que una pagination tiende a cambiar los valores de la otra.

```
// HTML ==============================
        <div class="l-pageProduct-card / js-dataPagination db-table" data-db-pagination="4, card product, db-table, 0, js-pagination-w" >
                <!--Card-->
            </div>              
            <footer class="l-pageProduct-pagination" >
            <!--PAGINATION-->
                <div class="pagination__2 / js-pagination-w" data-js-paginatonButton="pagination__2-button" ></div>
            </footer>
                        

            <div class="l-pageProduct-card / js-dataPagination db-tableTwo" data-db-pagination="2, card article, db-tableTwo, 1, js-pagination-w2" >
                <!--Card-->
            </div>              
            <footer class="l-pageProduct-pagination" >
            <!--PAGINATION-->
                <div class="pagination__1 / js-pagination-w2" data-js-paginatonButton="pagination__1-button" ></div>
            </footer>
```

```
// Variables ==============================
let js_dataPagination = document.getElementsByClassName("js-dataPagination");
let urls = ["../../assets/json/card-product.json", "../../assets/json/card-testimonial.json"];

//  Events call ==============================
for(p in js_dataPagination){
    databasePagination(p)
}

function databasePagination(p){
    let infoArray = [];
    // Obtiene y separa todos los valores de "data-atributo" en un array
    let infoData = js_dataPagination[p].getAttribute("data-db-pagination").split(",");
    // Formatea los caracteres no deseados por medio de "expresiones regulares (regex)" y almacena los resultados
    for(i = 0; i < infoData.length; i++){       
        infoArray.push(infoData[i].replace(/[$]|(^\s*)|(\s*$)/g, ""))
    }
    // Realiza "peticiones de red" para obtener información de una "base de datos (db)".
    let requests = urls.map(url => fetch(url).then(response => response.json()));
    Promise.all(requests).then(function(data){
    // Creamos un "objeto" para recopilar la información
    let objDataPagination = {
            'page': 1,  // Posición del "boton activo" de la paginación
            'items': parseInt(infoArray[0]),  // Numero de elementos requeridos
            'templateData': infoArray[1],  // Nombre de la tarjeta
            'window': 3,  // Tamaño de la paginación
            'siteData': infoArray[2],  // Lugar donde se imprimira el resultado
            'sitePagination': infoArray[4],  // Lugar donde se colocara la paginación
            'numero': p,  // Lugar donde se colocara la paginación
            'querySet': data[infoArray[3]]  // Guarda y selecciona la "base de datos" requerida
        }
        // Llamamos la funcion
        buildPagination(objDataPagination)
    })
}
```

```
function buildPagination(objDataPagination) {
    let estilo;
    let js_pagination_wrapper = document.getElementsByClassName(objDataPagination.sitePagination);
    let table = document.getElementsByClassName(objDataPagination.siteData);
    let data = pagination( objDataPagination.querySet, objDataPagination.page, objDataPagination.items)
    let myData = data.querySet
    let pages = data.pages

    for (i in myData) {
        let templateCreated = buildTemplates(myData, i, objDataPagination)
        table[0].insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', templateCreated);      
    }

// Calculos para obtener los botones de la paginación (NO MODIFICAR)
    let wrappe = "";
    let maxLeft = (objDataPagination.page - Math.floor(objDataPagination.window / 2))
    let maxRight = (objDataPagination.page + Math.floor(objDataPagination.window / 2))      
    if (maxLeft < 1) {
        maxLeft = 1
        maxRight = objDataPagination.window
    }       
    if (maxRight > pages) {
        maxLeft = pages - (objDataPagination.window - 1)              
        if (maxLeft < 1) {
            maxLeft = 1
        }
        maxRight = pages
    }
    for (let page = maxLeft; page <= maxRight; page++) {
        if(page == objDataPagination.page){
            estilo = "js-active";
        }else{ 
            estilo = "";
        }
        wrappe += `<button value=${page} class="paginationNav-button / js-pagination-button ${estilo}" >${page}</button>`;          
    }    
    if (objDataPagination.page != 1) {
        wrappe = `<button value=${1} class="paginationNav-button / js-pagination-button" > &#171; First</button>` + wrappe
    }    
    if (objDataPagination.page != pages) {
        wrappe += `<button  value=${pages} class="paginationNav-button / js-pagination-button" >Last &#187;</button>`;
    }
    js_pagination_wrapper[0].innerHTML = wrappe
                    
    let js_paginationButton = document.getElementsByClassName("js-pagination-button");
                        
    for(i = 0; i < js_paginationButton.length; i++){
        js_paginationButton[i].addEventListener("click", paginationButton)
    }
// Funciones al pulsar los botones
    function paginationButton(){
        table[0].innerHTML = "";        
        objDataPagination.page = Number(this.value)
        buildPagination(objDataPagination)
    }
}

// Calculos iniciales
function pagination(querySet, page, items) {
    let trimStart = (page - 1) * items
    let trimEnd = trimStart + items  
    let trimmedData = querySet.slice(trimStart, trimEnd)
    let pages = Math.round(querySet.length / items);            
    return {
    'querySet': trimmedData,
    'pages': pages,
    }
}
```

```
// Función para crear la tarjeta
function buildTemplates(myData, i, objDataPrints){      
    let templatesCollection = [
        {name: "card product", template:`
        <article class="cardProduct / js-item" data-tag=" ${myData[i].tag}">
            <div class="cardProduct-thumbnail / loading" >
                <img class="cardProduct-image" onload="renderCard()" src='https://picsum.photos/3${i}0/400?random=${i}' alt="${myData[i].title}" >  
            </div>
            <div class="cardProduct-info">
                <div class="cardProduct-content" >
                    <h3 class="cardProduct-title  loading" > ${myData[i].title} </h3>
                    <p class="cardProduct-text  loading" > ${myData[i].content} </p>
                </div>
                <div class="cardProduct-details  loading" >
                    <div class="cardProduct-feature">
                        <i class="cardProduct-icon / iconify"  data-icon="mdi:trophy-variant"  ></i> 
                        <p class="cardProduct-featureText" > ${myData[i].feature} </p>
                    </div>
                    <p class="cardProduct-price" > ${myData[i].price} <span class="cardProduct-old" > ${myData[i].priceOld} </span></p>
                </div>  
            </div>
        </article>
        `},
        {name: "card article", template:`
        <article class="cardArticle" >
            <div class="cardArticle-thumbnail  loading" >
                <img class="cardArticle-image" onload="renderCard()" src='https://picsum.photos/300/400?random=${i}' >
            </div>
            <div class="cardArticle-info">
                <div class="cardArticle-content " >
                    <p class="cardArticle-tag  loading" >${myData[i].tag}</p>
                    <h3 class="cardArticle-title  loading" >  ${myData[i].title} </h3>
                    <p class="cardArticle-text  loading" > ${myData[i].content} </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </article>
        `}
    ]

// Halla el template deseado
    let result = templatesCollection.find(result => result.name == objDataPrints.templateData);
    return result.template;
}
```

Comment: Si el codigo presenta algun error de gramatica referente a la programación; fue porque presente problema en el editor de Stackoverflow.. Por lo tanto señalo que ese NO es el problema..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He encontrado la solución, el problema surge porque la función `paginationButton()` se encuentra contenida dentro de la función `buildPagination()` por lo tanto en un principio todo funciona bién hasta que los botones de la paginación son presionado, debido a que éste ejecuta nuevamente `buildPagination()`; pero también vuelve a iniciar `paginationButton()` y a causa de este problema añadir más de una paginación genera errores porque se activa `paginationButton()` tantas veces como paginaciones existan..

La SOLUCIÓN es extrae `paginationButton()` donde esta contenida y dejarla como una función independiente y listo.. El resto es cuestión realizar algunos ajustes menores a dicha función para que se ejecute como antes..

Answer (score 0):

Al parecer, el problema es que estás usando `tableData` y `objDataPagination` como variables globales, se sobrescriben al crear varios elementos de paginación y genera un comportamiento inesperado al usar una sola variable para todos los elementos, debiendo ser independientes.

Lo recomendable, es definir las variables con la palabra reservada [let](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let), de forma que existan solo en el bloque donde fueron declaradas. El resto de funciones las recibe por parámetro. De preferencia, modifica el resto del código para cambiar `var` por `let` en todas las variables.

```
// Variable global
let baseDe = document.getElementsByClassName("js-datas");
// var tableData, objDataPagination; // No necesitas estas variables como globales

//  Inicio
for(let p = 0 in baseDe){
    databasePagination(p)
}

function databasePagination(p){
    let infos = []
    let dataPagination = baseDe[p].getAttribute("data-basa").split(",");

    for(let i = 0; i < dataPagination.length; i++){     
        infos.push(dataPagination[i].replace(/[$]|(^\s*)|(\s*$)/g, ""));
    }   
    
    // Supongo que la variable urls está declarada en otra parte del código que no incluiste
    let requests2 = urls.map(url => fetch(url).then(response => response.json()));
    Promise.all(requests2).then(function(data){     
        let number = infos[3];
        // Estas variables solo deben existir dentro de la promesa
        let tableData = data[number]
        let objDataPagination = {
            'page': 1,  // Posición del "boton activo" de la paginación
            'items': parseInt(infos[0]),  // Numero de elementos requeridos
            'templateData': infos[1],  // Nombre de la tarjeta
            'window': 3,  // Tamaño de la paginación
            'siteData': infos[2],  // Lugar donde se imprimira el resultado
            'sitePagination': infos[4],  // Lugar donde se colocara la paginación
            'numero': p  // Lugar donde se colocara la paginación
        }
        // Se usan las variables locales e independientes para cada paginación
        objDataPagination.querySet = tableData;
        buildPagination(objDataPagination);
    });
}
```

Con estos cambios, ya debería funcionar correctamente.

Comment: El codigo corre ; pero sigue presentando el mismo problema.. Funciona mal si se añade más de una paginación..

Comment: @nicolamendoza, por favor edita tu pregunta para agregar un ejemplo del código HTML que se va a paginar, es la única forma de probar si esto funciona o no.

Comment: He editado mi pregunta y amplie el codigo original, con todos los parametros para crear la paginación; he incluye las sugerencias realizadas y alguna  otra modificación menor.. No incluye el JSON porque este "no son el problema", para fines practico genere 2 JSON con datos diferentes y notara que al crear las 2 paginaciones una de ella tiende a gobernar a la otra..